# Установка Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors - что-то не так с кодировкой?

Tags: android-studio

```
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer
Requesting administrative privileges...
"CScript" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
Done
```

Вот такой скрипт мне пишет. Виртуализация в биос разрешена.
Ноут Asus TUF Gaming, система Win10.
Проблему нагуглить не могу :( Помогите с установкой, нужен эмулятор.

Comment: Удалось решить проблему? У меня такая же(

Answer (score 0):

Расшифровка текста:
"CScript" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

(исходная кодировка : WINDOWS-1251)

Answer (score 0):

в комментах на ютубе нашел решение, плюс к этому надо включить виртуализацию(в биосе) + в компонентах hyper-v, платформа виртуальной машины и песочницу
ну а решение такое -
"Артемий Хромцов
9 months ago
У меня был такой случай:  эмулятор, который ты создаешь, попадает в папку .android , которая находится по адресу: C:\Users{USER_NAME}, а в моем случае имя пользователя было названо с кирилицей (русскими буквами). Перемещаешь папку в другое место (полезно также для того чтобы освободить диск С, потому что потом эта папка будет весить очень много, несколько ГБ) , которое не имеет в названии кирилицы. в моем случае я переместил в D:\Android
а далее методом гугления "change .android folder location" первая ссылка на стэк оверфлоу

вкратце: надо создать переменную среды в разделе "Системные переменные" после того как вы переместили папку (да, Android Studio также надо закрыть перед перемещением)"